# share menu in Apple's iOS productivity apps (Pages, Keynote, Numbers)

Tags: ios

Is the share menu in the productivity apps a standard UIKit view controller?

[image: Share menu]

It looks similar to `UIDocumentMenuViewController`, which is used for the + menu. I'm guessing it's a custom thing, but just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a UITableView inside UIPopoverController.
Populate the table view's cell with the items you need and embed it into a UIPopoverController. You can present it from the UIBarButtonItem and will be just like the one you see above.

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/)

[One of the Great Tutorial for UIPopoverController](http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)